# How to solve the problem of 'CPU Limit Exceeded'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve the ["Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho" problem on Toph](https://toph.co/p/aaj-kemon-bodh-korcho):

> There is a match between Barcelona and Real Madrid. [...]  There is a
>   GOAL in each and every second of the match. All the goals may not be
>   valid i.e. some of the goals can be done from OFF SIDE  which is out
>   of the rules.
>
> [Output] “Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho” (without quotes) if Barcelona won the
>   match,  “Hala Madrid” (without quotes) if Real Madrid won the match or
>   “Meh :\” (without quotes) if there is no winner.
>
> [...] The goals that are done from OFF SIDE are belongs (sic) to a
>   famous series [...]:
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 …, …, …, …, …, n<sup>th</sup> term
>
> #### Input
>
> You’re given an integer number **T** which denotes the number of test
>   cases **(T <=100)**. In (sic) each of the **T** line contains a string
>   (**S**) of following characters **(B, M)**. The maximum length of the
>   string will not be greater than **10<sup>5</sup>**. Note that, the
>   starting index will be **0**.
>
> Here,
>   If the **i**<sup>th</sup> character is **B** then it denotes a
>   goal is done by Barcelona at **i**<sup>th</sup> second.
>   If the
>   **i**<sup>th</sup> character is **M** then it denotes a goal is done by Real Madrid at **i**<sup>th</sup> second.
>
> #### Output
>
> For each of the **T** lines you have to print the case number first
>   according to the format **Case #X** where X is the case number.  Then
>   you have to print **Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho** if Barcelona won the match
>   or **Hala Madrid** if Real Madrid won the match.  Otherwise print
>   **Meh :\** . For more clarification see the samples below.
>
> #### Sample
>
> ```
> Input   Output
>
> 2
> BBMMMM  Case #1: Hala Madrid
> MMBBBB  Case #2: Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho
> ```

Here's my code:

```
f=[0,1]
num_of_testcase = int(input())
store_2 = []
for i in range(num_of_testcase):
    numbers = input()
    store_1 = list(numbers)
    for x in range(len(store_1)):
        f.append(f[x]+f[x+1])
    f = sorted(set(f), key=f.index)
    for y in f:
        try:
            del store_1[y]
        except:
            store_2.append(store_1)
    if store_1.count("B") > store_1.count("M"):
        print("Case #" + str(int(i+1)) + ":" + " Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho")
    elif store_1.count("B") < store_1.count("M"):
        print("Case #" + str(int(i+1)) + ":" + " Hala Madrid")
    else:
        print("Case #" + str(int(i+1)) + ":" + " Meh :\\")
```

When I submit my code it shows CPU Time Exceeded on the second testcase. How can I make my code run faster?

Comment: Please [edit] your quesion to at least summarize the task your code is attempting to solve.

Comment: It's in the link of the problem

Comment: I can see that, but that's the problem here; questions on Stack Overflow should be reasonably self-contained. Links stop working over time, and some visitors are unable to click through.

Comment: All right then, I am editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program, you have this line  `del store_1[y]`. This is an O(n) operation according to [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). So, your code works in O(n<sup>2</sup>). That is why you are getting **CPU Time Exceeded**.

Maintain 2 counters , `b=0` and `m=0`. Iterate through the given string and find if the given index is part of the set, If yes, don't do anything. Else check if it is `B` or `M`. Accordingly, increment the counters and do the necessary check in the end.

Also, instead of generating Fibonacci series multiple times, you can actually generate it once and use the results again and again for the test cases.

Comment: I did exactly as you said but I still receive the same error on testcase 2. The time shown is much shorter now but still the same problem.

Comment: @MahirIslam You are getting timeout on Test case #2 again? Can you post your code in some online IDE and paste the link here in comments

Comment: @MahirIslam I have updated your code [here](https://ideone.com/PDMb4x). This should work. Let me know the results.

Answer (score -1):

There are several things that slow down your code:

- You start with *x* from 0 to reproduce the same Fibonacci numbers which you already generated for the previous test case. You should only generate those you did not have yet.
- Because of the previous point, you have duplicates which you need to get rid of by applying `set`, and then you have to sort that set. If you would only generate unique Fibonacci numbers, you would not have to perform those actions.
- `del` is not a constant time operation. You should not need to delete list elements at all. All you *really* need to do, is counting
- You potentially call the `count` method four times in a test case, while it should be enough to only perform a count once.

You can save more:

- Don't actually store the Fibonacci numbers in a list, but just keep the last two values in memory, and produce the next one once your index reaches the current Fibonacci number
- Keep track of *one* count, a balance, which will go positive when Madrid scores more, or negative when Barcelona scores more.

Here is how that could look:

```
num_of_testcase = int(input())
for i in range(num_of_testcase):
    goals = input()
    balance = 0
    # Fibonacci pair
    a = 3
    b = 5
    # Don't bother looking at index 0-3: they are to be ignored
    for j in range(4, len(goals)):
        if j < b:
            balance += 1 if goals[j] == "M" else -1
        else:
            a, b = b, a+b # Up to next Fibonacci number
    if balance < 0:
        print("Case #{}: Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho".format(i+1))
    elif balance > 0:
        print("Case #{}: Hala Madrid".format(i+1))
    else:
        print("Case #{}: Meh :\\".format(i+1))
```

Comment: This shows 'wrong answer' on the very first test case: https://toph.co/s/429702

Comment: I missed a space in the word ``Meh :\\``. Corrected now.

Comment: If you look into the link, you will see something like this:                                                     Expected Output:                                                                                                                           Case #1: Hala Madrid
Case #2: Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho                                                                                        Your Output: Case #1: Meh :\
Case #2: Aaj Kemon Bodh Korcho

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that, but that is what it's showing there.

Comment: Well, I cannot comment on that, without information about the input. Please find any input for which you think the output is not correct.

Comment: I cannot tell about the input from testcases but that is the point of solving the problems, to get the correct answer without knowing the input. If I knew the input I would have slowly found out where I was going wrong with the code and fixed it.

Comment: Can you explain why your solution returns "Meh :\" when the input is "MMBBB"? As far as I understood the question, the first four characters should be ignored, because they are at Fibonacci indexes. Can you explain?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the assignment. Can you answer my previous question?